# How do I replicate Bluetooth's CCM scheme in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ecb

I'm working on a firmware update scheme that requires end-to-end encryption of a firmware image. The target device is a Bluetooth Low Energy chip, with hardware support for the cryptography specified in Blueooth Spec, AES-CCM. We want to leverage this hardware to minimize code size and speed, so we need to encrypt a firmware image in the format for which the hardware is built.

So, I'm trying to use the .NET's [AesManaged class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged?view=netframework-4.7.1) such that I can reproduce the data samples given in the [Bluetooth Spec](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=421043&_ga=2.48670758.1048942298.1513973227-197487911.1513973227) (p 1547), but I'm not getting the same outputs. Here's the sample data:

> Payload byte length: 08
>   K: 89678967 89678967 45234523 45234523
>   Payload counter: 0000bc614e
>   Zero-length ACL-U Continuation: 0
>   Direction: 0
>   Initialization vector: 66778899 aabbccdd
>   LT_ADDR: 1
>   Packet Type: 3
>   LLID: 2
>   Payload: 68696a6b 6c6d6e6f
>
> B0: 494e61bc 0000ddcc bbaa9988 77660008
>   B1: 00190200 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   B2: 68696a6b 6c6d6e6f 00000000 00000000
>
> Y0: 95ddc3d4 2c9a70f1 61a28ee2 c08271ab
>   Y1: 418635ff 54615443 8aceca41 fe274779
>   Y2: 08d78b32 9d78ed33 b285fc42 e178d781
>
> T: 08d78b32
>
> CTR0: 014e61bc 0000ddcc bbaa9988 77660000
>   CTR1: 014e61bc 0000ddcc bbaa9988 77660001
>
> S0: b90f2b23 f63717d3 38e0559d 1e7e785e
>   S1: d8c7e3e1 02050abb 025d0895 17cbe5fb
>
> MIC: b1d8a011
>   Encrypted payload: b0ae898a 6e6864d4

For now, I'd be happy just to get encryption working without authentication. I've noticed that the MIC and Encrypted Payload are T and Payload XOR'd with S0 and S1, respectively, so my goal is simply to generate S0. My understanding is that I should be able to do this by ECB'ing the CTR0 array with the key K:

```
//I've tried a few endian-ness permutations of K, none work
byte[] sampleKey = { 0x23, 0x45, 0x23, 0x45, 0x23, 0x45, 0x23, 0x45,
                    0x67, 0x89, 0x67, 0x89, 0x67, 0x89, 0x67, 0x89};
byte[] sampleCtr0 = { 01, 0x4e, 0x61, 0xbc, 00, 00, 0xdd, 0xcc,
                    0xbb, 0xaa, 0x99, 0x88, 0x77, 0x66, 00, 00 };
byte[] encrypted;

using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
{
    aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //CTR implemented as ECB w/ manually-incrementing counter

    // Create an encrytor to perform the stream transform.
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(sampleKey, zeros); //zeros is a byte array of 16 0's

    // Create the streams used for encryption.
    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
            {
                //Write all data to the stream.
                swEncrypt.Write(sampleCtr0);
            }
            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to see S0 in *encrypted*, but I don't. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method `StreamWriter.Write(byte[])`. Instead, you were calling `StreamWriter.Write(object)`, which calls `ToString` on the object. This returned "System.Byte[]", which was then UTF8-encoded and written to your `CryptoStream`.

```
byte[] sampleCtr0 = { 01, 0x4e, 0x61, 0xbc, 00, 00, 0xdd, 0xcc,
                    0xbb, 0xaa, 0x99, 0x88, 0x77, 0x66, 00, 00 };
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var wri = new StreamWriter(mem))
    {
        //Write all data to the stream.
        wri.Write(sampleCtr0);
    }
    Console.WritELine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray()));
}
```

Produces:

```
System.Byte[]
```

Do not use `StreamWriter` for writing binary data to a stream. Either write the data directly to the stream using `Stream.Write` (as you did) or use a `BinaryWriter`.

`StreamWriter` is designed for writing characters which must be encoded to bytes through an `Encoding` passed to the constructor. This is defaulted to `Encoding.UTF8`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the use of StreamWriter was the problem. Upon removing that and replacing it with csEncrypt.Write(), I got my expected output.

I still don't really understand my fix, so I was about to edit this question, but seeing as the issue probably has nothing to do with cryptography, I think that would be better addressed as a separate question. Alternatively, if someone can explain the fix, I'll change the accepted answer to that.

EDIT: Dark Falcon got it.

Answer (score 0):

The stream, or one of its source streams, may need flush() before copying.  Otherwise it can truncate the end if unfinished.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my AES-CCM impelmentation, C# 2.0 compatible:

Note that some byte operation classes (e.g. XOR) that are available [here](https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary/blob/master/Utilities/Cryptography/AesCcm.cs) are needed:

```
/* Copyright (C) 2020 Tal Aloni <tal.aloni.il@gmail.com>. All rights reserved.
 * 
 * You can redistribute this program and/or modify it under the terms of
 * the GNU Lesser Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation,
 * either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 */
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Utilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements the Counter with CBC-MAC (CCM) detailed in RFC 3610
    /// </summary>
    public static class AesCcm
    {
        private static byte[] CalculateMac(byte[] key, byte[] nonce, byte[] data, byte[] associatedData, int signatureLength)
        {
            byte[] messageToAuthenticate = BuildB0Block(nonce, true, signatureLength, data.Length);
            if (associatedData.Length > 0)
            {
                if (associatedData.Length >= 65280)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Associated data length of 65280 or more is not supported");
                }

                byte[] associatedDataLength = BigEndianConverter.GetBytes((ushort)associatedData.Length);
                messageToAuthenticate = ByteUtils.Concatenate(messageToAuthenticate, associatedDataLength);
                messageToAuthenticate = ByteUtils.Concatenate(messageToAuthenticate, associatedData);
                int associatedDataPaddingLength = (16 - (messageToAuthenticate.Length % 16)) % 16;
                messageToAuthenticate = ByteUtils.Concatenate(messageToAuthenticate, new byte[associatedDataPaddingLength]);
            }

            messageToAuthenticate = ByteUtils.Concatenate(messageToAuthenticate, data);

            int dataPaddingLength = (16 - (messageToAuthenticate.Length % 16)) % 16;
            messageToAuthenticate = ByteUtils.Concatenate(messageToAuthenticate, new byte[dataPaddingLength]);

            byte[] encrypted = AesEncrypt(key, new byte[16], messageToAuthenticate, CipherMode.CBC);

            return ByteReader.ReadBytes(encrypted, messageToAuthenticate.Length - 16, signatureLength);
        }

        public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] nonce, byte[] data, byte[] associatedData, int signatureLength, out byte[] signature)
        {
            if (nonce.Length < 7 || nonce.Length > 13)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("nonce length must be between 7 and 13 bytes");
            }

            if (signatureLength < 4 || signatureLength > 16 || (signatureLength % 2 == 1))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("signature length must be an even number between 4 and 16 bytes");
            }

            byte[] keyStream = BuildKeyStream(key, nonce, data.Length);

            byte[] mac = CalculateMac(key, nonce, data, associatedData, signatureLength);
            signature = ByteUtils.XOR(keyStream, 0, mac, 0, mac.Length);
            return ByteUtils.XOR(data, 0, keyStream, 16, data.Length);
        }

        public static byte[] DecryptAndAuthenticate(byte[] key, byte[] nonce, byte[] encryptedData, byte[] associatedData, byte[] signature)
        {
            if (nonce.Length < 7 || nonce.Length > 13)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("nonce length must be between 7 and 13 bytes");
            }

            if (signature.Length < 4 || signature.Length > 16 || (signature.Length % 2 == 1))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("signature length must be an even number between 4 and 16 bytes");
            }

            byte[] keyStream = BuildKeyStream(key, nonce, encryptedData.Length);

            byte[] data = ByteUtils.XOR(encryptedData, 0, keyStream, 16, encryptedData.Length);

            byte[] mac = CalculateMac(key, nonce, data, associatedData, signature.Length);
            byte[] expectedSignature = ByteUtils.XOR(keyStream, 0, mac, 0, mac.Length);
            if (!ByteUtils.AreByteArraysEqual(expectedSignature, signature))
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("The computed authentication value did not match the input");
            }
            return data;
        }

        private static byte[] BuildKeyStream(byte[] key, byte[] nonce, int dataLength)
        {
            int paddingLength = (16 - (dataLength % 16) % 16);
            int keyStreamLength = 16 + dataLength + paddingLength;
            int KeyStreamBlockCount = keyStreamLength / 16;
            byte[] keyStreamInput = new byte[keyStreamLength];
            for (int index = 0; index < KeyStreamBlockCount; index++)
            {
                byte[] aBlock = BuildABlock(nonce, index);
                ByteWriter.WriteBytes(keyStreamInput, index * 16, aBlock);
            }

            return AesEncrypt(key, new byte[16], keyStreamInput, CipherMode.ECB);
        }

        private static byte[] BuildB0Block(byte[] nonce, bool hasAssociatedData, int signatureLength, int messageLength)
        {
            byte[] b0 = new byte[16];
            Array.Copy(nonce, 0, b0, 1, nonce.Length);
            int lengthFieldLength = 15 - nonce.Length;
            b0[0] = ComputeFlagsByte(hasAssociatedData, signatureLength, lengthFieldLength);

            int temp = messageLength;
            for (int index = 15; index > 15 - lengthFieldLength; index--)
            {
                b0[index] = (byte)(temp % 256);
                temp /= 256;
            }

            return b0;
        }

        private static byte[] BuildABlock(byte[] nonce, int blockIndex)
        {
            byte[] aBlock = new byte[16];
            Array.Copy(nonce, 0, aBlock, 1, nonce.Length);
            int lengthFieldLength = 15 - nonce.Length;
            aBlock[0] = (byte)(lengthFieldLength - 1);

            int temp = blockIndex;
            for (int index = 15; index > 15 - lengthFieldLength; index--)
            {
                aBlock[index] = (byte)(temp % 256);
                temp /= 256;
            }

            return aBlock;
        }

        private static byte ComputeFlagsByte(bool hasAssociatedData, int signatureLength, int lengthFieldLength)
        {
            byte flags = 0;
            if (hasAssociatedData)
            {
                flags |= 0x40;
            }

            flags |= (byte)(lengthFieldLength - 1); // L'
            flags |= (byte)(((signatureLength - 2) / 2) << 3); // M'

            return flags;
        }

        private static byte[] AesEncrypt(byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] data, CipherMode cipherMode)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
                aes.Mode = cipherMode;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```